# Drive name greyed out in safely remove hardware option and no eject option present

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, usb-flash-drive

The option to eject is not present and the drive name is greyed out.

[image: safely remove taskbar icon]

I tried `RunDll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL hotplug.dll` in Run and it is not able to stop there as well.

[image: safely remove hardware window]

I tried unmounting in diskpart. It said unmounted and made offline successfully, but still I could feel the hard drive spinning.

The safely remove option is available when I connect the drive to another computer running Windows 11. Same issue is present for pendrive or any other USB drive connected to this computer. I searched many forums but could not figure out what is wrong.

For pendrive there is Eject option in the right-click context menu in Explorer. Whereas, for external HDD this option is not there.

Edit: Irrespective of Quick removal or Better performance setting in the policy tab of properties, the eject option doesn't show in taskbar safely remove option. Same case for flash drive or external hard disk. It just shows the device name but not the eject option.

I'm suspecting some kind of display scaling issue, because my desktop icons spacing also increased abnormally around the same time as this issue started appearing and I saw two lines above the greyed out drive name, as if something is present above that and hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

- Open Disk Management
- Right click the drive

[image]

- Click 'Properties'
- Select policies TAB
- Select 'Better Performance' policy + enable write caching for better performance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Windows treats USB flash drives as devices frequently removed, and makes that easier by not caching writes. An external HDD usually *does* have write-caching turned on *to improve performance*, thus requiring proper removal, as you tried to do. Also, if that drive is currently *in use*, it cannot be removed. For example, Windows *Defender* might be busy scanning it, or *Search* indexing it, or it might be in use if *Documents*, *Music*, *Pictures*, *Videos* or other default Windows folders are on it.

There are [a number of ways](https://blog.pcrisk.com/windows/13336-cant-safely-eject-external-hard-drive-on-windows-10-4-ways-you-can-fix-it) to enable Windows *Safely Remove Hardware and Eject Media* to eject it. However, I've found Windows *Safely Remove Hardware and Eject Media* to be a bit of a nuisance, in this case, and as a workaround, use a third party tool, such as free [Hotswap!](http://mt-naka.com/hotswap/index_enu.htm), or [an alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/hotswap/), to eject the drive as a single step.

Comment: My problem is not just about stopping the drive, the eject option itself is not shown in the safely remove hardware option in taskbar as shown in the picture in the question. I don't see any explanation for this in the links pointed.